# find all the linked IDs in a text file with each row has two IDs that are linked

Tags: python

I have a text file with rows like below:
ID1 ID2
ID1 ID3
ID1 ID4
ID2 ID1
ID2 ID3
ID2 ID4
ID3 ID1
ID3 ID2
ID3 ID4
ID4 ID1
ID4 ID2
ID4 ID3
ID5 ID6
ID5 ID7
ID6 ID5
ID6 ID7
ID7 ID5
ID7 ID6
.....

I want to find all the linked IDs:
[ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4], [ID5, ID6, ID7]

I am bit new in python. Could you please share how to tackle this problem?

Thanks very much!

Ming

Comment: What have you tried so far and how did you go from the text file to that list?

Comment: I am more confident in using unix command lines. So, I got the ids by cut and sort uniq etc...

Comment: So you just want the unique ID's in the second column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this is not the best python but since you are new it will show you some basic concepts you can use in the future:

```
ld = {} # basic dictionary
# now open & read file
with open('linked_id.txt') as fin:
    for ln in fin: # process each line in the file
        k, v = ln.split() # split each line eg. k = 'ID1', v = 'ID2'
        # make a dictionary entry - setdefault puts the k(ey) in and
        # in this case set the value to a list, append then adds to 
        # the list by k(ey)
        ld.setdefault(k, []).append(v) 

unq = [] # start an empty list
for k, v in ld.items(): # process the dictionary elements
    v.append(k)  # make the value list include the key
    ll = sorted(v)  # sort the new list
    if not ll in unq: # see if its in the unq (unique) list
        unq.append(ll) # if not add it

print(unq)  # show the unique sets
```

now there are all sorts of library functions that can be used but this will get the job done

Comment: Thanks for your detailed scripts and comments! I can understand the very well. The only new thing to me is the setdefault method for dictionary. Thank you again for helping newbies like me.